# How to insert images dynamically based on cell value

Tags: excel, image, vba

I have two column

```
A         B

Cat
Lion
```

Pictures are in `c:\pictures` folder and are in `png` format.I have wrote code like this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, [A:A]) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Row Mod 20 = 0 Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo son
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Target.Value & ".jpg").Select
Selection.Top = Target.Offset(0, 2).Top
Selection.Left = Target.Offset(0, 4).Left
Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
Selection.ShapeRange.Height = Target.Offset(0, 2).Height
Selection.ShapeRange.Width = Target.Offset(0, 2).Width
Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
son:

End Sub
```

The formula works fine. But when i delete value of A2 or A3 , correspoding picutres did not deleted . And When I again write the item in A2 and A3, Pictures add above old pictures.

Also is there any way to delete picture if the values of cells `A2` and `A3` are empty?

Comment: Anything stopping you from putting an `onLoad` and `onChange` event for the cells in A and then having static image boxes in B whose source you set based on the value in corresponding A programmatically?

Comment: Formula is working fine. But I am so confused on deleting Pictures in  B when A is empty.

Comment: Why delete them? Why not just make the picture boxes invisible instead? There is a `visible` attribute you can set to false. I used something like this for the same purpose with access `[pictureBoxName].Visible = false`

Comment: Can you please show me in my above formula? it took me already few hours :(

Answer (score 0):

**edited** to handle picture absence/presence before adding/deleting it

you could name pictures with its *parent* cell address so that it's easy to reference them once you delete some *parent* cell content:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    If Intersect(target, [A:A]) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If target.row Mod 20 = 0 Then Exit Sub

    If Not IsEmpty(target) Then '<--| if changed cell content is not empty
        If Not IsPicture(target) Then '<--| if there's not a picture whose name matches the target address
            With Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\chojwa\Desktop\a\UT\VARIE\software\VBA programming\Forum\Stack Overflow\images" & "\" & target.Value & ".bmp") '<--| insert it
                .Top = target.Offset(0, 2).Top
                .Left = target.Offset(0, 4).Left
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .ShapeRange.Height = target.Offset(0, 2).Height
                .ShapeRange.Width = target.Offset(0, 2).Width
                .name = target.Address '<--| associate the picture to the edited cell via its address
            End With
        End If
    Else '<--| if cell content has been deleted
        If IsPicture(target) Then Me.Shapes(target.Address).Delete '<--| delete the picture whose name is associated to the cell via its address, if any
    End If
    target.Offset(1, 0).Select
son:
End Sub

Function IsPicture(target As Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsPicture = Not Shapes(target.Address) Is Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: but I don't know which errors and which line is throwing them

Comment: I put Value in Cell A1 and A2. 

Lets say Lion and Pig

Cell B2 and B3 shows picture of Lion and Pig.

Conditions
1. If I put random text then it gives error " 1004. Unable to get the insert property of the Pictures class"  in this line 

 With Pictures.Insert(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Target.Value & ".png")

2. If I edit A2 value and put Lion , picture of lion is above picture of Pig . Two pictures for one value

3. If I delete cell value 3 times (even it is empty), it gives error
The item with the specified name wasn't found.

Comment: just restore the `On Error GoTo son` statement at the beginning of the sub and the corresponding `son:` label right before `End Sub`

Comment: :( Not working.

If i directly delete cell value , Picture gets deleted
If I edit value manually , Picture gets overlapped by new one

Comment: see edited code: the code doesn't handle pictures that had already been inserted in the worksheet before its "appearance": so just delete all pictures and then start it all anew

Comment: I have put as you mention but, picture gets overlapped if I edit manually.

Comment: what do you mean by that? have you started with a new blank worksheet?